# Save to database post,but before check http request in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, save, httprequest

I am trying save hashes to my database but before I want check request 
I am using

```
require 'net/http'
gem 'http'
```

This is my controller (hashes I call :hammer)

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create]

  def create
    @payment = current_user.payments.build(payment_params)
    aza = ''
    uri = URI("https://blockexplorer.com/api/tx/#{:hammer}")
    res = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
    res1 = res.class.name
    aza += Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    @go = aza
    if aza.include?( '3MGeicHK6P2pUpepsXyTiuA7omMbRZbZx3') #'"addresses":["3MGeicHK6P2pUpepsXyTiuA7omMbRZbZx3"]'
      if aza.include? '"value":"0.03072025"'
        if aza.include? '"confirmations":0'
          flash[:info] = "Wait 15 minutes for confirm"
        else
          if @payment.save
            flash[:success] = "You paid"
            redirect_to root_url
          else
            render 'welcome/index'
          end
        end
      else
        flash[:danger] = "You paid less"
      end
    else
      flash[:danger] = "#{res1}"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def payment_params
    params.require(:payment).permit(:hammer)
  end
end
```

When I was try to save it is not check, it is just show error 400
But If I use console it is work

```
uri = URI("https://blockexplorer.com/api/tx/f484f14ebf9726ab2ab46ffc491786db50fc69ceff737620122e51559a3ea379")
irb(main):003:0> Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find want can to do

```
      @test = payment_params[:hammer]
   #   hammer = ''
   #   hammer += params[:hammer].to_s
      aza = ''
      uri = URI("https://blockexplorer.com/api/tx/#{@test}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the bug is there:

```
uri = URI("https://blockexplorer.com/api/tx/#{:hammer}")
```

in PaymentsController.
Try that instead:

```
uri = URI("https://blockexplorer.com/api/tx/#{params[:hammer]}")
```

You missed params[] in your interpolation.

Comment: When server do http request , it is do to "https://blockexplorer.com/api/tx/" , #{params[:hammer]} is empty